# Android Studio reads Music file as text file,How do I revert it?

Tags: java, android

`gameAlert.mp3` is my sound file.While running the app it asked me about that this file is not associated with any file type.Please define the association and I chose `TextFile` by mistake.Now my music file is read as a text file.How do I convert it back to `music file`?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MediaPlayer mPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.gameAlert);
        mPlayer.start();
    }
```

Comment: `Android Studio reads Music file` ???? Why would Android Studio read a music file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]you should be able to use it in-app irrespective of how Android studio treats it.

Just go to *File > Settings > Editor > File Types*

And select **Text**

Then remove the extension from the list below

Answer (score 0):

I mostly think its of no issue when it comes to building your application. The file would be read by Android Phone and not by Android Studio. If you are really concerned about this, the simply delete the file and re-add it and choose "Open file in its default application" something. 
I think this should fix your issue.

Comment: Since it is read as a text file , the app wouldnt run and it doesnt ask for an option like "Open file in its default application" when added again, it automatically treats it as text file

Comment: That has nothing to do with the app. The mp3 file is read in your device and not in Android Studio. Try what Tharaka said btw.