# Android studio - mp3 file is read as txt

Tags: android, android-studio

I've created a raw folder added my mp3 file there but android studio sees it as txt file after it (the file) is added to raw folder (even when I open this file in AS I see some random text) , because of that I can't create MediaPlayer to work with that file how can I change the way AS sees it?

Comment: What do you mean by " _pasting_"? You don't use the ids ?

Comment: When I paste mp3 file to raw folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio reads Music file as text file,How do I revert it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503749/android-studio-reads-music-file-as-text-file-how-do-i-revert-it)